# Truncate <a> tag text

Tags: javascript, html

In below code I'm attempting to truncate the `<a>` tag text :

```
<a href='test'>
    <script>
        truncate("truncate this text");
    </script>
</a>
```

```
function truncate(string){
    if (string.length > 5)
        return string.substring(0,5)+'...';
    else
        return string;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fcq6o4Lz/6/

But returns `error Uncaught ReferenceError: truncate is not defined`

How can this function be invoked from within `<a>` tag ?

Comment: You have to receive the output in `document.write` check the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why

The reason you get the error is because your computer hasn't run the code that defined `truncate` yet. That function is running before the page finishes loading, that includes the JavaScript. Put the code in a `window.onload` with a `setTimeout` to be safe.

```
window.onload = function(){setTimeout(function () {
    truncate("truncate this text");
},1);};
```

## How

Also, unlike languages such as PHP. `return` won't place any text. Do something like:

```
<a id="result-location" href='test'>
        <script>
        window.onload = function(){setTimeout(function () {

            document.getElementById('result-location').innerHTML = truncate("truncate this text");

        },1);};
        </script>
</a>
```

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44x1ao5p/5/)

---

### JSFiddle Fix

Remember to keep the function outside of a `window.onload`. You can change this in JSFiddle by setting it no no-wrap

[image: Choose No-wrap]

---

## CSS

You can use CSS to truncate text

```
.truncate {
    width: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will cause the text to truncate, after 50px;

```css
.truncate {
  width: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a class="truncate">This text is truncated</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't invoke javascript code like this. Although you could use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) to print result of javascript function into HTML element, it is stongly advised to avoid this, as it makes code really confusing.

Instead try something like this: select HTML element in question with CSS selector, select corresponding HTML element, and finally modify its inner content.

```js
function truncate(selector) {
    
    var obj = document.querySelector(selector),
        string = obj.innerHTML;
    
    if (string.length > 5) string = string.substring(0, 5) + '...';
    
    obj.innerHTML = string;
};

truncate('#link');
```

```html
<a href="test" id="link">truncate this text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to address the element with an ID, like this:

```
<a href='test' id="test-id">truncate this text</a>

<script>
function truncate(id){
    var string = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    if (string.length > 5) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = string.substring(0,5)+'...';
    }
};

truncate("test-id");
</script>
```

JSFiddle-Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c8s3dc6q/1/

Answer (score 0):

All javascript, including the function definition, should happen within a `<script> ... </script>` block. And that `script` block should stay in the end of the page, where the function "selects" the `a` tag with an id or class.

However I think that you might want to achieve the same results using pure `CSS`.

```
<a class="trim-text">This text should be trimmed!</a>

// add this to your css file / block
.trim-text {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

h1 {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the function before its call in the code, then use `document.write` to receive the output of the function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script>
    function truncate(string){
       if (string.length > 5)
          return string.substring(0,5)+'...';
       else
          return string;
    };

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  hhhhhhh<br />
<a href='test'>
    <script>
    document.write(truncate("truncate this text"));
    </script>
    </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Checkout this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gocuwoceja/1/)

Comment: `document.write` shouldn't really *ever* be used. It promotes bad practice

Comment: As the the code of OP he could not printout his function output without `document.write`. Secondly, what's the bad practice in `document.write` I think it is one of the first things one may know about DOM.

Comment: I was tempted to downvote solely because you suggested using `document.write`.  There are [many reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) it shouldn't be used. [Douglas Crockford on `document.write`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs#t=1082s). It is never a good idea to teach beginners bad habits, they might take them up without realizing they are bad habits.

Comment: Also, his problem originated because of `window.onload` and `document.write` will only *really* work before

Comment: The demo that I have offer, does not show any of points regarded in the signed answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice. Simply it works and it is the more near solution from the OP code.

Comment: Also you may checkout the second answer of that question too, http://stackoverflow.com/a/802894/1592845

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to a css only method there's a way to do that. It's based on width and not character count so more precise for styling.

fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/ufe1t66v/3/

html

```
<a class="truncated-anchors">This be way too long</a>
<a class="truncated-anchors">This too is too long</a>
<a class="truncated-anchors">This as well, far too long</a>
<a class="truncated-anchors">This one is even longer if I add some more words</a>
```

css

```
.truncated-anchors {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

A more thorough explanation

http://makandracards.com/makandra/5883-use-css-text-overflow-to-truncate-long-texts

And there are options to not use ellipsis and just end it immediately.